# What's a graceful way of doing an "if none of the above"?

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, boolean-logic

I'm sure you've been there.  You want to say "if flib do this, if flob do that, if flab do diet, etc" where any number of them can be true, then at the end you want an "if you didn't do ANY of them".

For example (the examples below are in Swift, as I've been playing with it, but I think the situation is the same in most languages):

```
let thing = 101
var isInteresting = false
if (thing % 3 == 0) {
    println("\"\(thing)\" is a multiple of three.")
    isInteresting = true
}
if (thing > 100) {
    println("\"\(thing)\" is greater than one hundred.")
    isInteresting = true
}
if (thing > 1000) {
    println("\"\(thing)\" is greater than one thousand.")
    isInteresting = true
}
if !isInteresting {
    println("\"\(thing)\" is boring.")
}
```

I find keeping track of a boolean to tell me whether I did anything or not kinda ungainly.

The only other way I came up with was this:

```
let thing = 101
let isAMultipleOfThree = (thing % 3 == 0)
let isGreaterThan100 = (thing > 100)
let isGreaterThan1000 = (thing > 1000)

if isAMultipleOfThree {
    println("\"\(thing)\" is a multiple of three.")
}
if isGreaterThan100 {
    println("\"\(thing)\" is greater than one hundred.")
}
if isGreaterThan1000 {
    println("\"\(thing)\" is greater than one thousand.")
}
if !(isAMultipleOfThree  || isGreaterThan100 || isGreaterThan1000 ) {
    println("\"\(thing)\" is boring.")
}
```

but if anything that's worse (if you add a new clause you need to remember to add it in three places.

So my question is, is there a neat, succinct way of doing this?

I'm dreaming of an imaginary switch-like statement:

```
switchif {   //Would have fallthrough where every case condition is checked
case thing % 3 == 0:
    println("\"\(thing)\" is a multiple of three.")
case thing >100 :
    println("\"\(thing)\" is greater than one hundred.")
case thing > 1000:
    println("\"\(thing)\" is greater than one thousand.")
none:   //Unlike 'default' this would only occur if none of the above did
    println("\"\(thing)\" is boring.")
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about the `else` keyword.

Comment: I don't think there is a neat alternative to what you did.

Comment: Go on, Piokuc, demonstrate how the "else" statement would help there.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question that does not have a perfect answer.  However, here's one other idea in addition to those you suggest:  **Encapsulate the testing machinery in a procedure to allow the calling code at least to be a bit more streamlined.**

Specifically, for your example, the calling code can be this:

```
if (! doInterestingStuff(101)) {
  println("\"\(thing)\" is boring.");
}
```

If testing is encapsulated into a procedure:

```
  public boolean doInterestingStuff(int thing) {
    var isInteresting = false

    if (thing % 3 == 0) {
      println("\"\(thing)\" is a multiple of three.")
      isInteresting = true
    }
    if (thing > 100) {
      println("\"\(thing)\" is greater than one hundred.")
      isInteresting = true
    }
    if (thing > 1000) {
      println("\"\(thing)\" is greater than one thousand.")
      isInteresting = true
    }

    return isInteresting
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a little neater in my opinion, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you'd do this in Swift, but since you didn't give a language tag I'll answer in C++.

The key to this is that `&&` is short circuiting, and the second part won't be evaluated when the first part is false. It's the same idea as your boolean flag, but it's a little more automated.

```
struct Tracker
{
    Tracker() : any(false) { }
    bool operator()() { any = true; return true; }
    bool any;
};

int thing = 101;
Tracker tracker;
if (thing % 3 == 0 && tracker()) {
    printf("\"%d\" is a multiple of three.\n", thing);
}
if (thing > 100 && tracker()) {
    printf("\"%d\" is greater than one hundred.\n", thing);
}
if (thing > 1000 && tracker()) {
    printf("\"%d\" is greater than one thousand.\n", thing);
}
if (!tracker.any) {
    printf("\"%d\" is boring.\n", thing);
}
```

See it in action: http://ideone.com/6MQYY2

Comment: Ooh, that looks nice!  Couldn't you just use a boolean for tracker, using && tracker = true?

Comment: @mazz0 I hate to abuse the `=` operator like that, and many compilers will generate a warning about it (rightly so). But I think it would work.

Answer (score 0):

kjhughes' answer inspired me a little:

Perhaps one could write a global function that accepts an indeterminate number of key-value pairs (or even just two element arrays), where the key is a comparison and the value is the statement to run if it's true.  Then return false if none of them were run, otherwise true.

Update:
Tried it, it's horrible!

```
//Function:
func ifNone(ifNoneFunc:()->Void, tests: Bool...)
{
    var oneTestPassed = false
    for test in tests
    {
        oneTestPassed |= test
    }
    if(!oneTestPassed)
    {
        ifNoneFunc()
    }
}


//Example:
let thisThing = 7
ifNone(
    {
        println("\(thisThing) is boring")
    },
    {
        if(thisThing % 10 == 0)
        {
            println("\"\(thisThing)\" is a multiple of 10")
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }(),
    {
        if(thisThing % 3 == 0)
        {
            println("\"\(thisThing)\" is a multiple of 3")
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }(),
    {
        if(thisThing > 1_000_000)
        {
            println("\"\(thisThing)\" is over a million!!")
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }()
)
```

Comment: Just noticed I didn't actually try what I described, but same thing more or less...